# Muliple character string replacement Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am scraping data from a dictionary and the returned data is `H` or `A`. In my for loop it is referred to as `home_away = stats['home_away']`.

I changed the string name to `h_a = home_away.replace("A","@")`

That works fine, but I also want to change `H` to `" "`.
Would I do a if statement or a for loop for that?

I tried

```
if home_away == "H":
   home_away.replace("H"," ")
elif home_away == "A":
   home_away.replace("A","@")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### One character replacement

If your input strings are either `H` or `A`, i.e. one character, I recommend you use a dictionary:

```
mapper = {'H': ' ', 'A': '@'}
home_away = mapper[home_away]
```

#### Multiple character replacement

If you have multiple characters to replace, you can chain [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) calls:

```
home_away = home_away.replace('H', ' ').replace('A', '@')
```

Alternatively, you can use a `mapper` dictionary as above with [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) and [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans):

```
home_away = 'HAAAH'
home_away = home_away.translate(str.maketrans(mapper))

print(res)
" @@@ "
```

Answer (score 3):

If the value is only a single character, why are you bothering with `.replace()` at all?  Just reassign the whole thing.

```
if home_away == "H":
   home_away = " "
elif home_away == "A":
   home_away = "@"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you exactly want, but an easy solution is to not use any if or else conditions and to simply just use:

```
h_a = home_away.replace("H"," ").replace("A","@");
```

This solution would ensure that any `H` character will be replaced with `" "` and any `A` character will be replaced with `@`. If there are no matches, then it would not throw any errors, instead it would retain the existing values stored within the variable and continue to run your script. .